# ios - Is it possible to record audio and play video from network stream at the same time?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, audio-streaming, facetime

I'm doing research for a iPhone video chat app project.

I've tried [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html) to capture image,
use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to display camera view
and put a `MPMoviePlayerController` to play network stream video at the back.

They all work until I add an audio input to the `AVCaptureSession`.
The `MPMoviePlayerController` stop the `AVCaptureSession` if there is audio input.

I think of using `AVAudioSession` for both playing and recording audio and some other way to play video,
but the documentation of `AVAudioPlayer` said

> "Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low I/O latency."

I found the **Multimedia Programming Guide** saying that

> "To provide lowest latency audio, especially when doing simultaneous input and output (such as for a VoIP application), use the I/O unit or the Voice Processing I/O unit."

Is it the correct direction to implement video chat in iphone?